# SQL Query to Return Rows Older than 15 Minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have a database that is used to process events (rows) to the Event Processor which then distributes the data into different database tables.

Lets call the table that pushes events to the Event Processor TableA.

If rows are left within TableA for a period of time (15 minutes), this means that there is a blockage in the Event Processor. This usually occurs when duplicate URIs are attempted to be inserted into the different database tables when the Event Processor tries to process them, leaving rows in TableA.

What would the SELECT query be for this instance? I'm not sure on how to dynamically set the date.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
select t.*
from t
where create_time < now() - interval 15 minute;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `create_time` -- or whatever the column is called.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `TableA` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),`column_name_here`) > 15
```

???